# How to parameterise the boolProp tag in jmeter jmx file for providing the input in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, load-testing, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

Context:

- Using JMeter 5.4.3
- Using JenkinsFile for setup
- Jmeter Thread group in .jmx has the below snippet:

```
        <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Test" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">${__P(Linf1,1)}</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">${__P(Tinf1,1)}</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">${__P(Rinf1,1)}</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">${__(TSch,false)}</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration">${__P(Dinf1,60)}</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay">1</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.same_user_on_next_iteration">true</boolProp>
        </ThreadGroup>
```

From the above TheadGroup section - I am facing issue with **[ThreadGroup.scheduler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vgkin.png)**

I am trying to parameterise this using ${__(TSch,false)} where the JenkinsFile -

- Accepts user input from Jenkins with these[parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAiio.png)
- And execution happens with the below usage :

```
jmeter_path/${params.testPlan} -GTinf1=${params.jmeterThread} -GRinf1=${params.jmeterRamp} -GTSch=${params.testScheduled} -GLinf1=${params.jmeterLoop} -GDinf1=${params.jMeterDuration} -Gconstant_throughput=${params.jmeterCT}
```

Issue am facing is from -GTSch=${params.testScheduled}

When I provide input as either true/false. It is not working as intended.

Example : I am giving the below details from Jenkins.

[Inputs from Jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ke6KB.png)

The script is running indefinitely as the loop given is -1 which led me to believe that schedule param is not working as intended.

**Please note - When I hardcode the scheduler value in jmx with true/false or change the tag to intProp and update it as 0/1. The script works as intended.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not something you can control using JMeter properties as of [JMeter 5.4.3](https://lists.apache.org/thread/dbg1bxywcwx5vtdwqf8ownf7ppgqjn41), the options are in:

1. Consider migrating to custom thread group i.e. [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/#Ultimate-Thread-Group) when the workload can be configured using [`threads_schedule` special property](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/#Special-Property-Processing)
2. Using a non-interactive editor like [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) to replace the default value in the .jmx file directly
3. Use [Taurus tool](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) as a wrapper for your JMeter test, it has possibility to [modify JMeter scripts](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Modifications-for-Existing-Scripts).